# Form input field Validation with regex on keypress using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Please I want to validate input fields on the form with regex on angularJS. Any help?

I have followed a tutorial online but validation with regex still didn't work.

```
<form id="search-form">
    <div class="row">enter code here
        <div class='col-md-4'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                <input required 
                       class="form-control" 
                       ng-model="form.applicant.Name" 
                       name="Name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone Number <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                <input required 
                       class="form-control" 
                       ng-model="form.applicant.phone" 
                       name="phoneNumber"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Please I want the Name Field to allow Alphanumeric and the Phone number field to allow only digits on keypress.

Comment: Inputs with no type default to `text` which already allows for alphanumeric values. If you want to only allow numbers you could add `type="number"` to your second input. You mention validation and regex, but then your code shows neither and then you mention you want to limit input on keypress - these are different things so it's not exactly clear what you want to do.

Comment: AngularJS has the [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) directive which adds a regex pattern validator to [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

Comment: in the first input field, I want to disable any other key except a-z, A-Z or 0-9 only. For the second input field I want to disable any other key except 0-9 only.